# A verb to mean not treating the work (especially one's job) seriously

Tags: single-word-requests

What is the verb that means someone **NOT** treating the work, usually the day-time job, seriously, like hoping to get things done as quickly as possible without careful double-check and always wanting to get out of the office as early as possible?

I found the word ["perfunctory"](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/perfunctory) which means "done quickly, without taking care or interest", which is what I mean but **I wonder if there is a corresponding verb**.

I also considered ["play at sth"](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/play-at-sth), but this phrase seems to be more suitable to describe "role playing". I could be wrong. Maybe "play at" is the right one for my question.

Any help?? Thanks!

Comment: People call that form of distancing *phoning it in* at work.

Comment: Other possibilities are "putz around" and its more Anglo-Saxon variants, but Yosef's proposal really is more on point than these.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you're looking for [*shirk*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/shirk) which Merriam-Webster defines as

> to evade the performance of an obligation.

The word is often used in the context of one's job.

Answer (score 0):

The perfect verb escapes me right now but I think the phrase "a slapdash approach to his (or her) work" might be work for you.